# Convert Access query to SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I'm trying to convert an MS Access query to SQL server, but I can't figure out the SQL server equivalent for the following code:

```
First(IIf(DateDiff("yyyy",[DateOfBirth],"31-Aug-2012")+Int(Format("31-Aug-2012","mmdd")<Format([DateOfBirth],"mmdd"))<18,'Parent/Guardian of:',Null)) AS PG, 
First(IIf(DateDiff("yyyy",[DateOfBirth],Now())+Int(Format(Now(),"mmdd")<Format([DateOfBirth],"mmdd"))<18,'Parent/Guardian of:',Null)) AS PG_old,
```

Here is my unfinished attempt:

```
First(CASE WHEN (DateDiff("yyyy",[DateOfBirth],"31-Aug-2012")+Int((DATEPART(mm,(CONVERT(DATE,"31-Aug-2012",103))) + (DATEPART(dd,(CONVERT(DATE,"31-Aug-2012",103)))))<Format([DateOfBirth],"mmdd")) < 18 THEN 'Parent/Guardian of:'
           ELSE Null)END) AS PG,
```

Comment: what you tried to convert this to SQL Server?  What have you tried?

Comment: As @bluefeet said, _[What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)_

Comment: SQL server has CASE which works like IIF.  It also supports DateDiff.  Give something a try, and then we can help...

Comment: I know I need top change the IIf's to CASE WHEN's, the bit I am struggling with is the Format(date), maybe using Convert and DATEPART i'm just not sure how to put it all together. I posted the Access code because mt SQL server code doesnt make much sense

Comment: Paste it anyway, we can modify it to work (by that I mean edit your question to include the code).

Comment: Also i am not sure why have you hard coded date as 31-Aug-2012

Comment: the code is a small part of a much larger query hard coding 31-Aug-2012 is necessary

Comment: Try this select top 1 (select case When DATEDIFF(year,'31-Aug-2012',DateOfBirth)< 18 Then 'Parent/Guardian of:' else Null  End  ) from table_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope below query would give you required output

```
 select top 1 (select case When  DATEDIFF(year, DateOfBirth, '31-Aug-2012') < 18 Then 'Parent/Guardian of:' else Null  End  ) from table_name
```